# How to reuse JS files used for a node.js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a set of JS files which I am currently using for a server side node.js API.

Files:

- CommonHandler.js
- Lib1.js
- Lib2.js
- Lib3.js

I need to reuse these JS files inside an ASP.NET application.

How can I bundle these files and reuse it for other applications? One of the options I can think of is to create an NPM package and include the NPM package inside an ASP.NET application. However, I do not want to upload internal JS files to public NPM server. Can the package be uploaded to an internal Nexus server? Has anyone done similar thing before? Is there any better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) to to package your Node.js project into an executable that can be run even on devices without Node.js installed

Comment: Thanks Sudhakar - I will have a look.

Comment: I had a quick look, it creates an executable. Not sure if I can integrate inside an ASP.NET application.

Comment: @developer The ASP.NET App u refer is server-side right (Having .NET Runtime)?

Comment: yes, the data comes from server side but I want to use the JavaScript libraries on client side on ASP.NET.

Comment: If these files are just for use in the front end, why not include them in the public folder of your ASP.NET app?

Comment: @developer what kind of APIs are there in those js files?

Comment: @developer you might need to have a look at http://browserify.org/

Comment: @tutiplain - I do not want to duplicate those JS files hence I am looking for a way to package them and reuse.